# Managing adView from another class

Tags: java, android, android-activity, admob, adview

I have an application. There are classes. For example i have these classes:

-MainActivity.java

-AppName.java

-GameScreen.java

-GamePlayScreen.java

I have advertise coded in MainActivity.java as following,

```
public class MainActivity extends AndroidApplication
{
    protected AdView adView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,      WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);

    AndroidApplicationConfiguration cfg = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
    cfg.useGL20 = false;
    View gameView = initializeForView(new AppName(), cfg);

    AdView adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

    AdRequest request = new AdRequest();
    request.addTestDevice("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
    adView.loadAd(request);

    layout.addView(gameView);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
    adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

    layout.addView(adView, adParams);

    setContentView(layout);
    }
}
```

I have a banner top center. It is good.
Here is AppName.java:

```
public class AppName extends Game
{
@Override
public void create() 
{
    Assets.load();
    setScreen(new GameScreen(this, Settings.STATE_START));
}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height)
{
    super.resize(width, height);
}

@Override
public void pause() 
{

}

@Override
public void resume() 
{

}

@Override
public void dispose()
{
    Assets.dispose();
    getScreen().dispose();
}
}
```

Everything is fine i still have a banner. But the problem starts here. In my GameScreen, there is a link goes to GamePlayScreen as:

It goes to GamePlayScreen there is no problem.

```
game.setScreen(new GamePlayScreen(game, i + 1));
```

Now i am in game play. But i don't want to see the banner here.

The question is, how can i disable my adView in GamePlayScreen? I experienced that if you try to modify MainActivity.java from another class, you see very good exceptions.

Thank you for answers and comments.
And i think it is a good example for the people who wants to integrate advertise in their apps.

Answer (score 0):

Declare your adView public static, and you should be able to access it via
activityName.AdView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

make sure you instantiate it though in your activity-

Comment: i made it public static adView in MainActivity.java as you told,  and called MainActivity.adView.setVisibility(View.GONE); in GamePlayScreen.java. It says NullPointerException. I was waiting for it, i tried to instantiate the MainActivity in the GamePlayScreen. I think i couldn't do it right. It says "E/AndroidRuntime(26070): java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()"

Comment: instantiate the adview in the class where the object is located-

Answer (score 0):

you can think of using strategic patter to change behavior at run time, for example

```
public class Game { 
    ShowAdBehavior showAdBehavior;

    void setShowAdBehavior(ShowAdBehavior qb)
    {
        showAdBehavior = qb;
    }   

    void performAd(){
        showAdBehavior.AdArea();
    }   

    public void display() {

    }
}



public class AppName extends Game {
    public AppName()
    {
        //set you default behaviour
        showAdBehavior = new CanShowAd();       
    }

}


public interface ShowAdBehavior {
    public void AdArea();
}


public class CantShowAd implements ShowAdBehavior{
    @Override
    public void AdArea() {
        // you can pass adView as a paramater here and setvisibility VISIBLE
        System.out.println("dont show ad");         
    }
}


public class CanShowAd implements ShowAdBehavior{

    @Override
    public void AdArea() {
       // you can pass adView as a paramater here and setvisibility GONE
        System.out.println("show ad");      
    }
}


public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

           // In your activity you can set the behavior


        AppName appName = new AppName();
        appName.performAd();        
        appName.setShowAdBehavior(new CantShowAd());        
        appName.performAd();        
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

show ad
dont show ad

Comment: Well, at last i agree that you can't modify your activity from another class after started an activity. You can only use its variables and write your advertise code in Another class.

Comment: yes, it is true. Because after activity killed, you cant reach its widget.